# Django: Query one to many relationship for existing relationship with certain attributes in the many-model

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, one-to-many

Lets say I have the following two models

```
Group(Model):
    attribute = CharField()

TranslatedFoo(Model):
    language = ForeignKey(Language)
    country = ForeignKey(Country)
    group = ForeignKey(Group)
```

Now I want to find all Groups, that have a TranslatedFoo in their translatedfoo_set with language_code='x' and country='y' **in one query**. Does something exist like:

```
Group.objects.filter(translatedfoo_set__language__code='x', translatedfoo_set__country__code='y')
```

I know this doesn't work. Maybe I need to rethink my table layout

Comment: Did you try `Group.objects.filter(translatedfoo__language_code='x', translatedfoo__country='y')`? [Relevant docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/): search the page for "reverse".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct query does not include the `_set` part:

```
Group.objects.filter(translatedfoo__language_code='x', translatedfoo__country='y')
```

Search for "reverse" on [this doc page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) for more details.